# Deep/recursive Required<T> on specific properties

Tags: typescript

Given a class like this:

```
class Example {
    always: number;
    example?: number;

    a?: {
        b?: {
            c?: number;
        }
    };

    one?: {
        two?: {
            three?: number;
            four?: number;
        }
    };
}
```

Is it possible to, for example, mark `a.b.c` and `one.two.three` as non-optional (required) properties, without changing `example` and possibly also without changing `one.two.four`?

I was wondering if there was some recursive version of [MarkRequired](https://github.com/krzkaczor/ts-essentials#MarkRequired) from `ts-essentials`.

**Use case:**

We have a ReST-like API that returns data where some properties are always defined, and others are optional and explicitly-requested by the client (using a query string like `?with=a,b,c.d.e`). We'd like to be able to mark the requested properties and nested properties as not including `undefined`, to avoid having to do unnecessary `undefined` checks.

Is something like this possible?

Comment: Typescript cannot "parse" things such as `"a.b"` (just a string) into meaning nested properties, so if that is part of what you're looking for (and I think it is), the answer is no. If you're more flexible on the syntax it's a different story.

Comment: If you're okay with a syntax like `MarkRequired<Example, { a: { b: { c: any } }; one: { two: { three: any } } }>`, let me know and I'll post an answer.

Comment: Isn't this exactly what [non-null assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator) are for?

Comment: @Patrick Roberts Then you're putting that burden on the consumer of the API, though. I think OP here wants to return a properly typed response that already includes this.

Comment: @Ingo Bürk No, I was quite sure that TS wouldn't be able to understand the `a.b` syntax, the question was more about marking `a` as required and then having properties under it also marked as required. Thanks.

Comment: @jcalz If your idea was about using something like an `Overwrite` type, I thought about that too, but I think that it may be a bit too verbose. Thanks.

Comment: @Patrick Roberts I actually thought about this just after I posted the question. Apart from what @Ingo Bürk mentioned, I also worry that developers will over-use it, even in cases where `undefined` *is* in fact part of the type. Thanks.

Comment: @Ingo Bürk Returning a properly typed object would be the ideal solution, but I don't think that it's possible without redesigning the API. Thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

So here is what I came up with to create a recursive `DeepRequired` type.

### Input

Two generic type parameters:

1. `T` for the base type `Example`
2. `P` for an union type of tuples, that represent our "required object property paths" `["a", "b", "c"] | ["one", "two", "three"]` (similar to lodash object paths via [get](https://lodash.com/docs/#get))

### Example flow

1. Grab all required properties in top level `P[0]`: `"a" | "one"`
2. Create intersection type/concatenation of required and non required object properties

We include all properties from `Example` and additionally create a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) to remove `?` and the `undefined` value for each optional property that is to be changed to required. We can do that by using the built-in types `Required` and `NonNullable`.

```
type DeepRequired<T, P extends string[]> = T extends object
  ? (Omit<T, Extract<keyof T, P[0]>> &
      Required<
        {
          [K in Extract<keyof T, P[0]>]: NonNullable<...> // more shortly 
        }
      >)
  : T;
```

3. The type must be somehow recursive for sub properties. That implies, we also have to find a way to "shift" types from the tuple `T` to iteratively get the next required sub property in the path. To do that, we create a helper tuple type `Shift` (more on the implementation shortly).

```
type T = Shift<["a", "b", "c"]> 
       = ["b", "c"]
```

4. Challenging thing is, we want to pass in an union of tuples (aka many required paths), not just one. We can make use of [distributive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#distributive-conditional-types) for this and use another helper `ShiftUnion` capable to distribute unions of tuples over the conditional type containing `Shift`:

```
type T = ShiftUnion<["a", "b", "c"] | ["one", "two", "three"]> 
       = ["b", "c"] | ["two", "three"]
```

5. We then can get all required properties for the next sub paths by simply selecting the first index:

```
type T = ShiftUnion<["a", "b", "c"] | ["one", "two", "three"]>[0] 
       = "b" | "two"
```

### Implementation

Main type `DeepRequired`

```
type DeepRequired<T, P extends string[]> = T extends object
  ? (Omit<T, Extract<keyof T, P[0]>> &
      Required<
        {
          [K in Extract<keyof T, P[0]>]: NonNullable<
            DeepRequired<T[K], ShiftUnion<P>>
          >
        }
      >)
  : T;
```

Tuple helper types `Shift`/`ShiftUnion`

We can infer the tuple type, that is shifted by one element, with help of [generic rest parameters in function types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#generic-rest-parameters) and [type inference in conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#type-inference-in-conditional-types).

```
// Analogues to array.prototype.shift
export type Shift<T extends any[]> = ((...t: T) => any) extends ((
  first: any,
  ...rest: infer Rest
) => any)
  ? Rest
  : never;

// use a distributed conditional type here
type ShiftUnion<T> = T extends any[] ? Shift<T> : never;
```

### Test

```
type DeepRequiredExample = DeepRequired<
  Example,
  ["a", "b", "c"] | ["one", "two", "three"]
>;

declare const ex: DeepRequiredExample;

ex.a.b.c; // (property) c: number
ex.one.two.three; // (property) three: number
ex.one.two.four; // (property) four?: number | undefined
ex.always // always: number
ex.example // example?: number | undefined
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#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-Z4uh7FkdkDlpQYKjI6EhjjoPTcGMxEGCnbXF4UuA-LkOOW9huk4OJg27pdgG+QePTYuak85pUOHWnLuLl5ifbgFhRe-75u4RIBgRFUeem+H-Ph6H8AC8VrIqqRNreA9gUOgP3J8mP2EZnKYucGs9mGO5xmOK41mn85-nZD55jZ6F8AMRwqpRdt6LUD0JIVABBfI+OhT44HChUNOaYmBpnYGKZMYwohdW8vNMuwcRLlELNODMP8MyywUBg4AWDOr6kwDpf++D9SEOITgUhDA0zL1XlQmhFg6G4K4WvJhBo2ahlSmZacvAWHp0zpgmR-s+5NxYUXMmApMEqPIuvYOH8xE4AkeEcAQA)

---

### Some polish (Update)

There is still some minor inaccuracy left: If we add property `two` also under `a`, e.g. `a?: { two?: number; ... };`, it also gets marked as required, despite not beeing in our paths `P` with `["a", "b", "c"] | ["one", "two", "three"]` in the example. We can fix that easily by extending the `ShiftUnion` type:

```
type ShiftUnion<P extends PropertyKey, T extends any[]> = T extends any[]
  ? T[0] extends P ? Shift<T> : never
  : never;
```

Example:

```
// for property "a", give me all required subproperties
// now omits "two" and "three"
type T = ShiftUnion<"a", ["a", "b", "c"] | ["one", "two", "three"]>;
       = ["b", "c"]
```

This implementation excludes equally named properties like `two`, that are in different "object paths". So `two` under `a` is not marked required anymore.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#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-044EuwLAYaMX4xr3MEQxo4aDYBaj2x0QTRxgMWoNQMDsOlWWhQXCl01+8tM11NpMaYDu6RNugtwORWQdzZKPsDiuRNa59ZtmS0keRbu94qd5ODHAlsuDuLOaRoLDj+OTwLTgJn-Ms1oIYKdPB2h1OkRwG8dUIEAIP4vIjTcABEVh-qQf6yEBUB-kof68FAAA+UD-uUEBgX+y7ISmm5Qao-BMrgyi1DgUAhnQrDiMUL7tCEXRfg0TLUOmvyyL8SgHFAAD0rG6NWgo4qAwJKNuWAnFQ9HLix7GcQKQq8VcPZHuWsFQGgDAQHCtK4EJvyIb8y7aRu8BiRxOhcVJ4JXHpEACRpWk6XuB4GRJ3HCsCtmHgJClKbhql4BpGbevZvk+s2x4aYWj4QPZoXFnJOLucpXnqUAA)

### Possible extensions

- For single required properties pass in strings instead of tuple paths for convenience.
- Current implementation is suitable for a few object paths to be marked required; if multiple nested sub properties from an object are to be selected, the solution could be extended to receive object literal types instead of tuples.

---

Hope, that helps! Feel free to use that as a base for your further experiments.

Comment: This is *amazing*, thank you. When it's just one property, like `example`, it might be cool if that didn't have to be a tuple (like `"example" | ["one", "two"]`), but that's just a minor thing that wouldn't be worth implementing if it complicated things.

Comment: @glen-84 Thanks! That single string type would be a possible convenience extension, you're right. Btw: I added a minor fix to the `ShiftUnion` type, have a look at the updated answer.

Comment: Now with template literal types I bet this could be rewritten to work with a string syntax like "one.two.three" :)

Comment: Yep, this type will convert a string type like `"a.b.c.d"` to `["a", "b", "c", "d"]` so you can use the above answer with the following for a more familiar syntax :)

  ```type PathToStringArray<T extends string> = T extends `${infer Head}.${infer Tail}` ? [...PathToStringArray<Head>, ...PathToStringArray<Tail>] : [T]```

Comment: Wondering @ford04 how the `ShiftUnion` type works though - still lost on what the outer `T extends any[]` ternary is doing given that T already is assert to extend `any[]` in the generic, but it does seem to be necessary, as when I remove it my tests fail!

Comment: @osdiab the purpose of `T extends any` is to distribute *each* union member over the `extends` clause, so that `ShiftUnion<"a", ["a", "b"] | ["a", "c"]>` becomes `["b"] | ["c"]` (see [TS docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#distributive-conditional-types)).

Comment: Is it possible to keep `null` in the property types? For example, if `c` was `number | null | undefined`, just remove `undefined` and not `null`? That is how the regular `Required` type works.

Comment: I think that I've made it work by replacing `NonNullable` with a `NonUndefined` type (`type NonUndefined<T> = T extends undefined ? never : T;`).

Answer (score 17):

This worked well for me:

```
//Custom utility type:
export type DeepRequired<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: Required<DeepRequired<T[K]>>
}

//Usage:
export type MyTypeDeepRequired = DeepRequired<MyType>
```

The custom utility type takes any type and iteratively sets it's keys to required and recursively calls deeper structures and does the same. The result is a new type with all parameters on your deeply nested type set to required.

I got the idea from this post where he makes a deeply nested type nullable:

```
type DeepNullable<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: DeepNullable<T[K]> | null;
};
```

https://typeofnan.dev/making-every-object-property-nullable-in-typescript/

Thus, this method could be used to change arbitrary attributes of the deeply nested properties.

Comment: I think that you might have missed the "on specific properties" part of the question.  BTW, you can shorten `DeepRequired<T>` by using `[P in keyof T]-?: DeepRequired<T[P]>;`.

Comment: For anyone who finds this:
`type DeepRequired<T> = { [K in keyof T]: DeepRequired<T[K]>} & Required<T>`
is probably the best thing to use.

Comment: @Zarjio And why is that?

Comment: To clarify, the solution provided by @Zarjio is slightly different from the answer. It is complete in the sense that it marks every property in the type passed to `DeepRequired` as required, not just the nested ones (which is what the solution in the answer does).

Answer (score 6):

I augmented ford64's answer with template literal types to allow for specifying the paths using dot-separated strings, which looks a lot more familiar in syntax than arrays of keys. It's not 100% the same since you can't express a key with a `.` in it; square brackets dont work (`[]`); and you can express keys in a way that javascript wouldnt allow like `a.b-c.d` for `obj.a[b-c].d`; but these are pretty minor, and it would be pretty simple to augment this type to at least support the brackets case if someone really wanted it.

[Here's a playground link demonstrating it!](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PQKhCgAIUhxBTALgZ0gQwDYcvD8C28AdijgB4DG8ADopAGYD2ATpABbxoAmkAlkegFpmzNAE8oMAALwyafNTyTIAFTS8MAHgDaARgA0kAEyGAzAF0AfAG5IwYJG0nIFycHCIx1eKvVaV5IjEXKgArkQA1kSMAO5E2laQALyqgcGo2uFRsUSGAHQF-PTwrABK8MiI5lCQAPyQ5ZU1AFyQRPAAbiXW4OCgENANSKHMRKhqGpoqlnz0DLzMlTh4hCSQjHMB+GiIFByoAAp5kADKjIRssZDMFYwYXai8yMihFZAxvIhsyuG8jAKebzIQwAI1CdHCLxu7FitikyHgPgA3lIMPwIuxEIhqMhmvZKmgKBFGF1mPQMLE8hRzsA0MAAKwAdgAHKYWQBORnAXS6AAM9KMzN0AF83B4vD4JhgAKpEP5ETQHNJEEKQLLROKGAKyIIqsKRDXxRIpbVkXWq9U5BI1eoqbS88zK1UHGqQOq+SbTV2QVrtUktNqdbq9frKADC-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-fA-2-q0ABy-zE65GATXgkPw-DYM3GVaUZVVx3aIl5han4srypoiWGF9jD0-AliWHD0M2GLkCirTotuq0x3AaGgwQawJnQTZWnIUQqHodhWFfD4eEEURHQkb50JUZA3kkLYMQsBEqAfF8yikTQGDQe0lSccgYgkGgZCgtBOWJlbJR-DwAAUc55HOACUXHoJApFotdQTMHkkjKDIcgKEogxFRBBYpEi6C1K0zggmXkAlxQVemIYXCtAALFLUvKEVfaHULjMVdQmiFxWaBpjYdgOEiaDl6CVc13XDfN630swEVABCXc-W1SUpb3-eMIwwXD7Y-Xj1XFetDPrT10n8-Cm3+cSpAy9hmv+M9xlO97zWTkH6P1doCfoJnwshfOekAW430Xnme+fZH7Pw3q-Gg79B65gAD6fxzCPI+E9jAAOrkAlwICwG3xAO4NiLA6BFW7lvN+Kh+anQnL2acxU4FUMqiISGNDGptkvN1G8X5FSiwluAeg4RELyjzBURAlDyoZQjvHWGboioqAkcdLSh0S5-3LrYSugDa4X1sI3UBC9gIKKgbA0qLC+5KMqCoxCSCMFjywRXaeFlZ5X0MeA3oJjvCQGgdwKxiBdBqJvh1PUPj3R+lXK0NMjAIhph6G6akYw6BoGXn4iRuhWi+K4P4wJKRomxPiZA7xWT-FGDUegC+rcQmqk7vUCJrAokxLiTURJSwUlpMqEYTJqTskSLKXkppxiik+D7LAXevTKi5NwY4qpZpOq1JrE0-89TCmtOSWMxgEyAmZI2VsqZ+Tmk1BXmYhmFipjKLMkhT+39MH-3cjo1xBjCGiiOffZePSclBNOqvOpQYGmLIKS0-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-pPTdeDL47ulsMnxj9Q1fInbh-d0641ks7W0kE3acmpr2ZekDeHs1IrzRG+ZU6mWkdLckyjxLulVq1UBsjHcGNUu1dXcdqKalsdjf2hJiaJpUYkRyojfaO1Cb4xI5dJdG0BvE5G0DjLpMdrnfJhdyml10fVaB-F9ImMPvQ1h06+mi3-KM3J7jUL6S8esxZnDVmoUADZRNbufTpt9qAnNtpcxm8jXGFOVH815gLdH6M3oA9CoVjjH2+u3a+ljoSIufsi5x9AlGz1EYvQJnooogA) I edited the names of the types a bit, simplified some types and got rid of unnecessary uses of `any`, though I still don't understand how the `ShiftUnion` type from the previous answer works to solve the issues, so I left it.

Basically you take ford04's answer and just wrap the paths to require in the `PathToStringArray` type.

```
type PathToStringArray<T extends string> = T extends `${infer Head}.${infer Tail}` ? [...PathToStringArray<Head>, ...PathToStringArray<Tail>] : [T]

// ford04's answer, then

type DeepRequiredWithPathsSyntax<T, P extends string> = DeepRequired<T, PathsToStringArray<P>>
```

Result is you can use a dot-separated syntax to make these paths instead of wordy array syntax, like so:

```
type Foo = { a?: 2, b?: { c?: 3, d: 4 } }
type A = RequireKeysDeep<Foo, "a">; // {a: 2, b?: { c?: 3, d: 4 } }
type B = RequireKeysDeep<Foo, "b">; // {a?: 2, b: { c?: 3, d: 4 } }
type BC = RequireKeysDeep<Foo, "b.c">; // {a?: 2, b: { c: 3, d: 4 } }
type ABC = RequireKeysDeep<Foo, "a" | "b.c">; // {a: 2, b: { c: 3, d: 4 } }
```

Tests are in the playground link.

Comment: Nice! I was wondering if this was possible when I was reading about template literal types.

Comment: I don't suppose there's a way to make this work with arrays? It does work for a specific index, like `roles.0.id`, but it'd be awesome if we could use something like `roles.*.id` or `roles.[number].id`.

Comment: The other thing that I'm looking for is to just `Pick` the properties, instead of marking them as required. f.e. `Pick<Foo, "a" | "b.c">` or `Pick<Foo, "a" | "b">` (where all properties of `b` are picked, in addition to `a`).

Comment: The former is probably possible - the type would get more complex but basically when you see * you'd replace that with `any` in the array. It would break keys that have a * in it but who uses those in key names?

The latter is pretty simple - use the `PathToStringArray` helper above, then I believe this should work:

`type PickDeep<T, P extends string> = Pick<T, PathToStringArray<P>[number]>`

Comment: oh nevermind taht doesn't work but for `PickDeep` but its definitely possible in the same way that `DeepRequired` works, just haven't taken the time to work it out.

Comment: Can you provide extend the type to use the arrays star notation proposed by @glen-84 ?

Answer (score 5):

A slightly modified variant of this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/67833840/12631321 (I don't have enough reputation to comment) worked great for me and introduced less garbage in intellisense hints:

```
type DeepRequired<T> = Required<{
    [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends Required<T[K]> ? T[K] : DeepRequired<T[K]>
}>
```

Idea is that a type is the same as its Required wrapper, then we can skip it using conditional typing.

Comment: Logged in just to upvote :)
Worked great for my use-case! (had intellisense functions running me crazy..)