# How to retrieve type of a nested property in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, vue.js

Given the following declarations (which I don't want to change), how can retrieve the type of the `members` property specifically?

```
export type Members = {
  __typename?: 'Members';
  id?: Maybe<Scalars['String']>;
  ...
};

export type ProjectQuery = {
  __typename?: 'Query';
  Project?:
    | {
        __typename?: 'Project';
        teams?:
          | Array<
              | {
                  __typename?: 'Teams';
                  members?:
                    | Array<
                        | {
                            __typename?: 'Members';
                            id?: string | null | undefined;
                            ...
                          }
                        | null
                        | undefined
                      >
                    | null
                    | undefined;
                }
              | null
              | undefined
            >
          | null
          | undefined;
      }
    | null
    | undefined;
};

export type ProjectData = NonNullable<ProjectQuery['Project']>;
```

In my `Vue` store, I tried this:

```
async myStoreAction(context, { Members }: { members: NonNullable<ProjectData['teams']['members']> }) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

`NonNullable` applies to the end result of whatever is passed as its type parameter, so you'd have to wrap each nullable property with it, e.g. `NonNullable<NonNullable<ProjectQuery['Project']>['teams']>`, etc. Using `& {}` also rules out null and undefined, so it can be used to write *slightly* more readable code:

```ts
type ProjectData = ProjectQuery['Project'] & {};
type Members = ((ProjectData['teams'] & {})[number] & {})['members'];
async myStoreAction(context, { members }: { members: Members }) { ... }
```

---

It's probably going to look ugly no matter what you do. If you'd like a utility that makes your type and all its children non-nullable, I recommend [this other SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57835286/deep-recursive-requiredt-on-specific-properties).