# How do I make typescript utility type Required work for the nested members?

Tags: typescript

I want to use Required and make the members not optional. It works just fine. But, it doesn't work for the nested members of the interface. Is there a way to tell typescript that all the members will not be undefined?

```
interface Camera {
    id? :string;
    name? : {
        firstName?:string;
        secondName? :string
    };
    site? :string
}


const firstCamera :Required<Camera> ={
    id :'1',
    name :{},
    site :'hello world'
}
```

The above code works fine for the first members. But, firstName and secondName are still optionals. I would like to make them mandatory fields as well. Is there a way? Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deep/recursive Required<T> on specific properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57835286/deep-recursive-requiredt-on-specific-properties)

Answer (score 0):

You can split the **Camera** interface. Create some type **Name** and put names. For the **Camera** interface create a generic. Then use the  utility twice. [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAcghgW2gXigbwFBW1AZgSwCcBnYeJAfgC4pTD8A7AcwG4sdiIBjAewYBNyEarWD1mbAL4ZGwCIVxwu0AMKJ5cADwAVAHzp22fPxF1GrQ1AbqR2tjlr45pseakYMvBqTxFSapEI4KCoAJQgARwBXIgh+TQCNTXDo2PihXUyoZEwHYyoAcgBGAoAaS2skKlyHHAISMnUaAoBZOAAPMssHTi9BJqgCgBEeCALLSXKep2hCgAsIABtFnigAdx5CRf5x6S8fXr5+RKCQlJjCOIT1IM0M-RzLfOKuh0qIasnLYhmQgoXlqsNlsdhg9nwfMA5kRjjdglQTloMtkakZ+IUSlMcAB6bFWJpoL7TOR-AErdabba7DBAA)

```ts
type Name = {
    firstName?: string;
    secondName?: string;
}
interface Camera<T> {
    id?: string;
    name?: T;
    site?: string;
}
const firstCamera :Required<Camera<Required<Name>>> ={
    id:'1',
    name:{},
    site :'hello world'
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could remove conditional modifiers on the firstName, secondName properties of name. Name is still optional but if it's included firstName & secondName have to be too.

```
interface Camera {
    id?: string;
    name?: {
        firstName: string;
        secondName: string
    }
    site?: string
};
```

Comment: I see. But, that is not a great solution for my case. I can remove it manually like that. That is how I solved for temporary. But, there are a lot of fields. firstName and secondName are not the only members. There are tons of them with their nested members. So, I am kind of looking for a way to do it automatically, if there is any. Anyway thanks for the help. Really appreciate it.

Comment: I recommend this then:
export type DeepRequired<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: Required<DeepRequired<T[K]>>
}
export type CameraRequired = DeepRequired<Camera>;
Modified from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67833840/15407577